# libpq, insert with parameters

Tags: postgresql, libpq

I am wondering if I can make parameterized queries directly from C/C++ with libpq instead of using strings and if do how should this code look's like?

```
string tblins = "";
tblins = "INSERT INTO " + commtable + " "
         "(vdoc, bdoc, mytime, txml) VALUES ("
         "'" + cxml.vdoc + "', "
             + cxml.bdoc + ", " //integer
         "'" + cxml.mytime + "', "
         "'" + cxml.txml + "')";

result = PQexec(conn, tblins.c_str());
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `PQexecParams` function as explained [in the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-EXEC-MAIN).

> If parameters are used, they are referred to in the command string as `$1`, `$2`, etc. `nParams` is the number of parameters supplied; it is the length of the arrays `paramTypes[]`, `paramValues[]`, `paramLengths[]`, and `paramFormats[]`.

Comment: it's also recommended you typecast parameters, so `$1::integer, $2::varchar` etc, so you can pass `NULL` for the `paramTypes` arg